# How to fix 'react-native run-android' launch error "Resetting to invalid mark"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, gradle-plugin

I began to work with react-native a week ago.
So I've setup react-native as it described here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html  (TAB Building  projects with native code)
Then I initialized new react-native project with "react-native init..." command
As well I've setup Android Studio, created virtual android device, and launched android emulator
After that I entered command react-native run-android from project directory.
As a result I've got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject2'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.3.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.3.0
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.2/httpmime-4.5.2.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.2.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.2.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.5.2/httpcomponents-client-4.5.2.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                           > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/7/project-7.pom
                              > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.3.0
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.3.0
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.5.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.5/httpcore-4.4.5.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.4.5.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-core:4.4.5.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.4.5/httpcomponents-core-4.4.5.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                           > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/7/project-7.pom
                              > Resetting to invalid mark
   > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.3.0
      > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2.
         > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.pom
            > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.2.
               > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcomponents-client:4.5.2.
                  > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.5.2/httpcomponents-client-4.5.2.pom
                     > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                        > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:project:7.
                           > Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/7/project-7.pom
                              > Resetting to invalid mark

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I don't understand what is "Resetting to invalid mark" in this case and how to fix it.

using:
win 10
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.1
android gradle plugin 3.3.0 (tried 3.2.1 as well, d
doesn't help)
gradle 4.10.2 (tried 4.7, doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. Uninstalled all tools like node, python, expo, react-native-cli, deleted gradle repository and all cached files (npm-modules and others) and after that installed again from scratch. And it works now. So the reason was either some unnoticed error took place during previous installation or historical confusion in my os